# snmpv3 authentication with sha and md5

Tags: cisco, switch, snmp

I am facing this issue in my snmpv3 deployment. In some of catalyst cisco switches I am using snmpv3 with authpriv as sha and aes256. The porblem is that when I run an snmpwalk for v3 credentials it timesout. Though I have noticed that if i change the authpriv to MD5 and DES it runs fine and results successful.

I wanted to know why this behaviour on IOS accepts the sha/aes but doesn't respond? Any help?

Comment: What are the switch models, IOS versions, and SNMP configurations?

Comment: I didn't mention the switch model and IOS version as this is not with a specific IOS or switch model. I have cat6500 running ios v15.x and some other cat like 3700 series with ios v12.

Comment: The answer could actually depend on the IOS version. You should edit your question to include the IOS version and the SNMP configurations.

Comment: It is unreadable in a comment. Edit your question to include the information, and use the Preformatted Test feature (`{}`).

Comment: this is what I am using in my devices and the version of device
{ CSR1#sh ver
Cisco IOS Software, s72033_rp Software (s72033_rp-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 15.1(2)SY9, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

snmp config:<br/>
snmp-server group snmpgroup v3 priv read v1default write v1default access MGMT-ACL
snmp-server user User Group v3 auth sha xyz priv aes 256 abc access MGMT-ACL 
snmp-server host ip ver 3 priv User }

Comment: sorry but not able to put the comments in correct format I dont know how to do that, tried your help sections too :(

Comment: As I explained in my comment, you do not put configurations in comments. You edit your question, and use the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`).

Comment: Found the solution, it was the issue with snmpwalk in linux system, there is no provision of selecting AES 256 and by default it takes AES128 key which was mis-mtach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was the issue with snmpwalk in linux system, there is no provision of selecting AES 256 and by default it takes AES128 key which was mis-mtach.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.